# Problems with selenium to grab a last Whats app Question

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, npm

I'm having some problems to catch the last message from the user in WhatsApp Web, to be honest, I have no idea how I will catch this, I'm trying to solve this with xPath, merging absolute with relative, can someone help me with ideas and code ?

Comment: You may have to rewrite the sentence "between last div on code, have more div".  That doesn't make sense to me.  What did you mean by that?  Also, if you're having trouble with your xpath, then it might be helpful to include sample input with your question.

Comment: You right (Y), doesn't really make sense

Comment: Its simple now but is exactly what i need